# Swagger In Laravel: Set Parameter Example for Json Data

Tags: php, json, laravel, parameters, swagger

I have working on swagger in Laravel. I have set examples for the parameter with string type. but I have no idea how to set the example for JSON object data. I have below example data for JSON type.

```
*   @OA\Parameter(name="training_availability",example="{'Saturday':{'status':'true','start':'09:00','end':'18:00'}}",in="query", required=false,
*      @OA\Schema(
*          type="string"
*      )
*   ),
```

but there is an issue with `""` and `''` data set in example for JSON type.

any one help with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need:

`example={"Saturday":{"status":"true","start":"09:00","end":"18:00"}}`